# How to get minimum values with in a partition table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a sample table using the below code

```
WITH tab as(
 select * from UNNEST([STRUCT(timestamp('2019-05-11 18:04:15') as create_time, 101 as jobid, 'rkc' as user),
 (timestamp('2019-05-11 18:04:15'), 101 , 'ash'), (timestamp('2019-05-11 18:04:15'), 101,'adi'),

 (timestamp('2019-05-20 18:04:15'), 102 , 'rkc'),
 (timestamp('2019-05-20 18:04:15'), 102 , 'ash'), (timestamp('2019-05-20 18:04:15'), 102,'adi'),
 (timestamp('2019-05-20 18:04:15'), 102 , 'sri')

 ]))

 select * from tab
```

from the above table i want to fetch only minimum jobid and minimum create_time for each user

I am expecting the below kind of output[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

can anybody help me on this

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to fetch **only** `minimum jobid` and `minimum create_time` for `each user`

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  MIN(create_time) create_time, 
  MIN(jobid) jobid, 
  user
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY user
```

If to apply to sample data from question

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([STRUCT
    (TIMESTAMP('2019-05-11 18:04:15') AS create_time, 101 AS jobid, 'rkc' AS user),
    (TIMESTAMP('2019-05-11 18:04:15'), 101 , 'ash'), 
    (TIMESTAMP('2019-05-11 18:04:15'), 101,'adi'),
    (TIMESTAMP('2019-05-20 18:04:15'), 102 , 'rkc'),
    (TIMESTAMP('2019-05-20 18:04:15'), 102 , 'ash'), 
    (TIMESTAMP('2019-05-20 18:04:15'), 102,'adi'),
    (TIMESTAMP('2019-05-20 18:04:15'), 102 , 'sri')
]))
```

result is

```
Row create_time                 jobid   user     
1   2019-05-11 18:04:15 UTC     101     rkc  
2   2019-05-11 18:04:15 UTC     101     ash  
3   2019-05-11 18:04:15 UTC     101     adi  
4   2019-05-20 18:04:15 UTC     102     sri
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number()

```
select * from
(
select * , row_number() over(partition by user order by create_time) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and min() to achieve this.

```
select create_time, min(jobid), user from UNNEST group by user, create_time
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

By using `row_number()`. You may find more info about `row_number` from this link.[ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
 with ct as
 ( select jobid, user, create_time, 
   row_number() over (partition by Jobid order by create_time ) as Slno 
   from yourtable
 )
 select * from ct where slno = 1
```

OR

You may use aggregate function with `group by`. For more info about this you may find this link. [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

By using `MIN`

```
SELECT JOB_ID, USER, MIN(CREATE_DATE) AS CREATEDATE FROM YOURTABLE GROUP BY JOB_ID, USER
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a subquery using some built-in functionality:

```
select as value ARRAY_AGG(tab ORDER BY create_time DESC LIMIT 1)[ordinal(1)]
from tab
group by jobid
```